# Export PDF of decisiontree

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

i'm using scikitlearn to introduce me to Machine Learning, i' m following this tutorial [link to yt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNa99PG8hR8&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIIuiBfYad6rFYQU_jL2ryal&t=0s&index=2)
but if i try to export the pdf decision tree i have this error: 
i try to do: open -w review iris.pdf
and the result is :

```
Impossibile ottenere un descrittore di file che si riferisce alla console
```

if i compile from the terminal i have the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)  File "fstraining.py", line 2, in <module>
import graphviz ImportError: No module named graphviz
```

Thanks for the attention

Comment: The error is stating that you are missing a required module, did you try installing `graphviz`?

Comment: thank you for the answer, but i have install anaconda, and now it ask me some module, how can i check if it see i'm using anaconda for that module?
@EdChum

Comment: At the anaconda prompt enter `conda install graphviz`

Answer (score 2):

Once you have built your decision tree `clf`, simply:

```
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO   
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import pydotplus

# Export resulting tree to DOT source code string
dot_data = export_graphviz(clf,
                           feature_names=col_names,
                           out_file=None,
                           filled=True,
                           rounded=True)

#Export to pdf
pydot_graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)
pydot_graph.write_pdf('tree.pdf')
```

This answer is adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51346827/how-can-i-specify-the-figsize-of-a-graphviz-representation-of-decision-tree):