# How can I specify the figsize of a graphviz representation of a decision tree?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, graphviz

I have a `GraphViz` representation of a decision tree trained on the iris dataset.

```
import graphviz 

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None, 
                     feature_names=iris.feature_names,  
                     class_names=iris.target_names,  
                     filled=True, rounded=True,  
                     special_characters=True)

graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)
graph
```

I am using the above code to generate the `GraphViz` figure, but it creates a large graph.

I want to manually control the `figzise` of this graph. How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After initially writing my own function to modify the DOT source code string to add in a size attribute, I stumbled upon this section in the [`pydotplus.graphviz.Graph` documentation](http://pydotplus.readthedocs.io/reference.html#pydotplus.graphviz.Graph):

> All the attributes defined in the Graphviz dot language should
>       be supported.
>
> Attributes can be set through the dynamically generated methods:
>
> ```
>  set_[attribute name], i.e. set_size, set_fontname
> ```

You can see an example of using this below. Note the syntax when calling the function, as the DOT source code requires double quotes around the width and height. The exclamation mark means it will force the image to resize until one of the dimensions matches one of the specified dimensions, which only seems to matter if the dimensions specified are larger than the original size of the graph.

```
import pydotplus
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz

# Load in the dataset from sklearn
dataset = load_breast_cancer()
X = dataset.data
y = dataset.target
col_names = dataset.feature_names

# Create and fit the decision tree
clf_dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = 'gini', max_depth = 3)
clf_dt.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Export resulting tree to DOT source code string
dot_data = export_graphviz(clf_dt,
                                feature_names=col_names,
                                out_file=None,
                                filled=True,
                                rounded=True)

pydot_graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)
pydot_graph.write_png('original_tree.png')
pydot_graph.set_size('"5,5!"')
pydot_graph.write_png('resized_tree.png')
```

Click on the pictures to get a sense for size since it doesn't seem to show up properly in the browser.

**original_tree.png:**
[image: original tree]

**resized_tree.png:**
[image: resized tree]

Note also that `pydotplus.graphviz.Graph` objects have a `to_string()` method which returns the DOT source code string of the tree, which can also be used with the `graphviz.Source` object in your question:

```
import graphviz
gvz_graph = graphviz.Source(pydot_graph.to_string())
gvz_graph
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution and your detailed explanation :)

Comment: No problem. I learned quite a bit while putting together this answer. Glad it could be of use to you. =)